# Valid constructor invoking in memory management

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

I have written own memory library which helps me to avoid memory leaks and to avoid fragmentation problems. All works fine. The main problem is it doesn't work valid with classes. When i call my_alloc(size) i want to automatically call constructor if it exists. Can i do it without overloading new operator?

Comment: This depends- you will need to post more of your API.

Comment: I suspect your own memory library doesn't really improve upon the malloc implementation provided by your OS.

Comment: @DeadMG: It's kind of linear allocator. If doesn't go into details it is similar to this:
void *memory_pool = malloc(10000);

void *my_alloc(size)
{
return first_free_section_in_memory_pool;
}

Comment: And I suspect it hides memory leaks rather than avoids them.

Comment: The standard memory manager has been in development for over 2 decades its pretty good. It is unlikely that you will be able to improve on it without the equivalent amount of work (i.e. you are already 30 man years behind the curve).

Comment: A better way to avoid memory leaks is to use the tools that have already been build. i.e. smart pointers and containers (these are C++ version of deterministic fine grain garbage collection).

Comment: @Martin: Well, there *is* tcmalloc and jemalloc, which are awfully good improvements over the standard implementations. They do have a few drawbacks of their own such as increased memory use.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: Yes there are other memory management implementations available. The ones you mention seem to already have many many years of work invested in them. Like all things when you tune something for specific situations it will always do better in **that** situation than a general purpose variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *[placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)* on your allocated memory, to invoke the constructor without letting `new` do the allocations.

What's wrong with overloading `new`?

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly what i need.

Overloading new is not wrong, but i have some details why i can't do this. One of them is that i'm using several "memory modules" at one time due to specific of my application. So i always need to pass a "ctx" as a parameter when i call my_alloc(ctx,size). That's why i can't just overload "new".

Comment: @Oleg : Wrong assumption; when you overload `new` you can add extra arguments. So you'd call `T* ptr = new(ctx) T(ctorArgs);`

Answer (score 1):

Check your C++ implementation. Some of them (I think the G++ compiler does this) call the C Runtime `malloc` to get the memory for `new`, then call the constructors.

If you have one of those implementations, all that you need to do is properly override the standard library malloc and free functions (read the library internals documentation) and C++ will work automatically.

Comment: There is no legal way to override malloc/free

Comment: @Martin: Many libraries offer hooks intentionally designed to allow overriding malloc and free.

Comment: @Martin: glibc offers __malloc_hook, __realloc_hook, __free_hook, etc.

Comment: @Martin: I also believe that the glibc functions are defined as weak, which allows them to be overridden by any other function with the same name. This lets you load a malloc library of your own.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: Anything is possible to-do if you put your mind too it. That does not make it legal.

Comment: @Martin: The confusion must be in how you are using the word "legal". To me, if the library offers a feature then it is legal to use it. It is implementation-specific, yes, but legal. For example, it is legal to use the syscall macros to call Linux system calls that aren't yet offered through the C library.

Comment: @Zan: Legal mean allowed by the C++ standard. Which explicitly states that you can not change standard functions.

Comment: While it's perfectly legal (Implementation defined behavior is _allowed_ by the standard, even though it's not portable), the answer misses the point. Replacing `operator new` is well defined.

Comment: @MSalters: My answer works just fine if his new memory allocator is a complete replacement for malloc. If he replaces the functions below the level of `new`, he doesn't have to worry about calling the constructor because it will just happen. I think that does address the point of the question.